# Can't get correct format in Athena when reading from CSV file

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue, amazon-athena

So I have this csv file in S3 and I'm trying to read it off Athena using Glue. It looks like this in my computer:

```
+-------------------+-------------+------------+-------------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+--------+---------+----+-----+
|tweet_id           |ticker_symbol|company_name|writer       |post_date |body                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |comment_num|retweet_num|like_num|post_time|year|month|
+-------------------+-------------+------------+-------------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+--------+---------+----+-----+
|1024364727789600768|TSLA         |Tesla Inc   |evacuationboy|2018-08-01|This kinda stuff never worked to sell cars, most of all super heavy no off road ones - $tsla                                                                                                                                                                       |0          |0          |1       |00:12:37 |2018|8    |
|1024392683119423488|TSLA         |Tesla Inc   |sbalatan     |2018-08-01|WHOA.Beside exceptionally detailed support for his already public Whistleblower claims, Martin Tripp also accuses $TSLA of serious accounting fraud.  The whole counterclaim must be read by any stakeholder of Tesla.Each paragraph is more damning than the next.|0          |0          |0       |02:03:42 |2018|8    |
|1024397232391553025|AAPL         |apple       |j_p_jacques  |2018-08-01|$AAPL 40% earning growth17% revenue growthat it trade for less than 10 2018 earning adjusted for net cashat that growth thy can return $900B to shareholder in less than 6 years                                                                                   |0          |2          |3       |02:21:47 |2018|8    |
|1024398885329010688|AAPL         |apple       |HaiderSF     |2018-08-01|Timely on $AAPL marketing from Ken Segall:                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |0          |0          |4       |02:28:21 |2018|8    |
|1024402095540260871|AAPL         |apple       |SignoreRomeo |2018-08-01|In Q3, $AAPL pay completed more total transactions than $SQ & more mobile transactions than $PYPL                                                                                                                                                                  |0          |1          |1       |02:41:06 |2018|8    |
+-------------------+-------------+------------+-------------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+--------+---------+----+-----+
```

I have configured the following options in the glue catalog table as well:

```
Serde serialization lib: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde
Serde parameters: escapeChar='\\' quoteChar='"' separatorChar=','
```

But the problem is, the columns with commas inside are still getting split up into separate columns like so:

```
+------------------+-------------+------------+---------------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+----------+-----------------------------------+----+-----+
|tweet_id          |ticker_symbol|company_name|writer         |post_date |body                                                                                                                                                                                                              |comment_num                                                                                                                                                  |retweet_num  |like_num  |post_time                          |year|month|
+------------------+-------------+------------+---------------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+----------+-----------------------------------+----+-----+
|638421173571854340|AAPL         |apple       |plutonetworks  |2015-09-01|"""\""Move to android fast. ""\""@CNBCnow: Apple"""""Cisco announce partnership where Cisco will optimize networks for iOS users. • $AAPL $CSCO""\""\"""""0"1"00:10:43"                                           |2015                                                                                                                                                         |09           |null      |null                               |null|null |
|638435638623211520|AAPL         |apple       |_CardiacKid    |2015-09-01|$AAPL - Correction to Former Apple Supplier GT Advanced to Cut 40% of Workforce Article http://ih.advfn.com/p.php?pid=nmona&article=68350537&xref=newsalerttweet&adw=1126416…                                     |0                                                                                                                                                            |0            |0         |01:08:12                           |2015|09   |
|638447486319759360|GOOG         |Google Inc  |drwendellcraig_|2015-09-01|"""Sanofi buys into Google's #biotech  future"                                                                                                                                                                    | pairing up in #diabetes http://fiercebiotech.com/story/sanofi-buys-googles-biotech-future-pairing-diabetes/2015-08-31?utm_campaign=SocialMedia… $sny $goog""|0            |0         |0                                  |2015|09   |
|638598799171166208|AAPL         |apple       |PortfolioBuzz  |2015-09-01|Screen through high rated articles at once for US Tech Kings $AAPL $GOOG $FB http://cityfalcon.com/watchlists?name=US%20Tech%20Giants…                                                                            |0                                                                                                                                                            |0            |0         |11:56:32                           |2015|09   |
|638496755907194880|GOOG         |Google Inc  |ADVFNplc       |2015-09-01|$GOOG - India's Google Investigation Moves Forward http://uk.advfn.com/news/DJN/2015/article/68352601?xref=newsalerttweet&adw=1126416…                                                                            |0                                                                                                                                                            |0            |0         |05:11:03                           |2015|09   |
|638646145787559936|AAPL         |apple       |ArjunKharpal   |2015-09-01|Apple apparently wanting to do a Netflix and make original programming:  $AAPL                                                                                                               |1                                                                                                                                                            |0            |0         |15:04:41                           |2015|09   |
|638503830179704832|AAPL         |apple       |MarketSmith    |2015-09-01|Apple trails Fitbit in its first full quarter on the wearables market: https://washingtonpost.com/news/the-switch/wp/2015/08/28/apple-trails-fitbit-in-its-first-full-quarter-on-the-wearables-market/… $AAPL $FIT|0                                                                                                                                                            |1            |2         |05:39:10                           |2015|09   |
|638649417390784513|AAPL         |apple       |JohnyTradr     |2015-09-01|How Does Newmont Measure Up To Its Peers? http://snip.ly/JmG7 http://investwall.com #stocks #trading #investing $FB $AAPL                                                                                         |0                                                                                                                                                            |0            |0         |15:17:41                           |2015|09   |
|638591792024317952|"""AAPL"     | GOOG       | MSFT""        |"""apple" | Google Inc                                                                                                                                                                                                       | Microsoft""                                                                                                                                                 |PortfolioBuzz|2015-09-01|"""Stay ahead with Nasdaq 100 news"|2015|09   |
|638666551546220544|AAPL         |apple       |MoneyMarketzz  |2015-09-01|We Sent A SECRET New Penny Stock Pick To Our Platinum Members! Get Exclusive Special Access:  $DO $ALL $AAPL                                                                                    |0                                                                                                                                                            |0            |0         |16:25:46                           |2015|09   |
+------------------+-------------+------------+---------------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+----------+-----------------------------------+----+-----+
```

The columns are split along each comma. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, I've looked it up on stack overflow too but nothing helps.

Thanks in advance.

```
tweet_id,ticker_symbol,company_name,writer,post_date,body,comment_num,retweet_num,like_num,post_time
550501828547190784,AMZN,Amazon.com,Scott_Klemke,2015-01-01,"\"\"\"@WSJ: Jeff Bezos lost $7.4 billion in Amazon's worst year since 2008: http://on.wsj.com/1BmKuz3 $AMZN\"\"\"",0,0,0,09:30:38
550589778908164098,TSLA,Tesla Inc,Gold_prediction,2015-01-01,Stock Market Outlook: An Average Return Of 26.51% In A Year  #aggressives #risk #stocks $TSLA $GILD $RAD,0,0,0,15:20:07
550510764042121217,AAPL,apple,smoran26,2015-01-01,*FEATURE PRESENTATION* - THE MASSACRE: PART ONE - Stock of the Year - $AAPL Computer #Vegas #NYE  http://stephenjohnmoran.com/a-writers-diary/feature-presentation-the-massacre-part-one-stock-of-the-year-aapl-computer-vegas-nye… via @weebly,0,0,0,10:06:08
550670427388121088,MSFT,Microsoft,stockwire24,2015-01-01,Microsoft Corporation Is About to Abandon Internet Explorer $MSFT ,0,0,0,20:40:35
550612060946829312,AMZN,Amazon.com,caroltheva,2015-01-01,Free guide to understanding risk graphs $AMZN $FB $TWTR,0,0,0,16:48:39
550888743654400000,AAPL,apple,pricatti,2015-01-02,"#Balances #resultados #cartera #portfolio$aapl 26/01 EPS 2,56$king 02/02 EPS 0,37 $baba 16/02 $swhc 02/03 $csiq 03/03",0,0,1,11:08:06
550652617341566976,"AMZN, AAPL","Amazon.com, apple",SentiQuant,2015-01-01,#TOPTICKERTWEETS $IMRS $AAPL $SPY $IGN $FB $A $BABA $WAG $AMZN $QUAD #sentiquant 20150101 09:00:07:309,0,0,0,19:29:49
550927186169827330,MSFT,Microsoft,investingjungle,2015-01-02,"$IBM Possible inverse H&S forming on the daily, bullish with a close above 50sma towards gap resis $qqq $spy $MSFT  http://stks.co/t1Dwi",0,0,0,13:40:51
550693344372723712,AAPL,apple,MacHashNews,2015-01-01,Find the masks of power and master the elements in Lego Bionicle Mask of…  #AppAdvice $AAPL,0,0,1,22:11:39
551005616328949760,AAPL,apple,louwhiteman,2015-01-02,"Seeing fewer $AAPL products at my local $SBUX. Not sure if that is a #tech trend, or sign my neighborhood is on decline.",0,0,0,18:52:30
550781053137616896,AAPL,apple,CNBC,2015-01-02,This is Wall Street's top pick in 2015. Hint: it's NOT $AAPL or $GOOGL » http://cnb.cx/1xsBWIT,5,37,22,04:00:10
551016874700734464,AAPL,apple,aje0420,2015-01-02,Top ideas going into 2015 $AAPL $TWTR $VZ $C $UPS $YHOO #GLTA,0,0,0,19:37:14
550782974263037952,AAPL,apple,ramlousl,2015-01-02,"\"\"\"@CNBC: This is Wall Street's top pick in 2015. Hint: it's NOT $AAPL or $GOOGL » http://cnb.cx/1xsBWIT \"\"\"",0,0,0,04:07:48
551039971986264065,AAPL,apple,yonsu18,2015-01-02,"$AAPL last 5 days down on low volume, about 17 mil traded in the first hour, keep thinking funds getting out no bids taken today, all sell",0,0,0,21:09:01
```

[image: csv file in notepad+]

Comment: Can you remove serde parameters and let Athena use default values for these?

Comment: Can you please show us a sample of the _actual_ CSV file? I presume it does not contain the table formatting (`+---+---+---+`)?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy, I tried that too, but to no avail

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, I've added a screenshot and pasted the csv file content. Not sure if I can post the file here, please let me know if this is not enough, I'll try to upload the file into a google drive folder or something, thanks

Answer (score -1):

Frankly, I often find that it is easier to ask AWS Glue to determine the table format, rather than configuring it manually. Here's the steps I use:

- Make sure the file(s) are in their own directory because Glue assumes all files in a directory are the same data format (sort of)
- In the AWS Glue console, add a new Crawler
- **Add information about your crawler:** Give it a name
- **Specify crawler source type:** Use defaults
- **Add a data store:** Provide an "Include path" to point to your data, eg `s3://bucket-name/folder/`
- **Add another data store:** No
- **Choose an IAM role:** Create an IAM role and give it a name (you can delete the role later)
- **Create a schedule for this crawler:** Run on demand
- **Configure the crawler's output:** Select your desired database where the table will be created
- Finish

The settings are mostly default values, except for name, input path and IAM Role.

You can then **Run crawler** and after a minute or so it will create a table definition in the AWS Glue catalog that should also appear in Amazon Athena. (If it does not appear in Athena once the crawler has finished, see [FAQ: Upgrading to the AWS Glue Data Catalog - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/glue-faq.html#faq-benefits)).

Comment: Thing is, I did try that, but I get the same results as above. I tried setting up the serialization lib and serde parameters to solve it but I get the same results. I changed the delimiter to "|" when writing the csv file and now everything works fine. I'm still learning about this so I'm not sure how common it is in the industry to change the delimiters. Could you please tell me if that acceptable?

Comment: The problem with CSV format is that commas are commonly found in text. This is fixed by wrapping the value inside quotation marks. This then causes a problem when quotation marks are _also_ contained in the text, resulting in the `\"` symbols in your example file. Using pipe (`|`) is a good way around this problem, because it is extremely rare in text, so it will rarely conflict with the data itself. In fact, Hadoop uses pipe as a default separator due to this fact. Bottom line: If it works for you, then use it!

Comment: Great! Thanks for helping!